# Expected value of number of 3 red card sequences in a random shuffle of cards?

Tags: probability

This was a question that I've seen before, and it came up in an interview and I couldn't get an answer. It seems like there is some reduction to make this problem simple but I couldn't  find it.

Suppose you have a standard shuffled deck of cards. Let $X$ be the amount of times a red card follows two other red cards. What is $E[X]$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$X= \sum_{k=1}^{50} \mathbb 1_k$
where $\mathbb 1_k$ is an indicator random variable taking the value $1$ if the $k$th card in your shuffled deck is red *and* the $(k+1)$th card is red *and* the $(k+2)$th card is red.  This occurs with probability
$p=\frac{26}{52}\cdot\frac{25}{51}\cdot \frac{24}{50}= \frac{2}{17}$.

These indicator r.v.'s are highly dependent but Linearity of Expectations still applies, so

$E\Big[X\Big] = E\Big[\sum_{k=1}^{50} \mathbb 1_k\Big]=\sum_{k=1}^{50}  E\Big[\mathbb 1_k\Big]=\sum_{k=1}^{50}p = 50\cdot p=\frac{100}{17} $

Comment: This is great, thank you

Comment: This isn't right.  A quick simulation shows the answer to be more like $5.88$.  In fact you need to have $p=(1/2)(25/51)(12/25)=6/51$, so $E[X]=300/51 \approx 5.8824$.

Comment: @mjqxxxx OP asked about 3 *reds* consecutively but I answered about 3 *Hearts* consecutively for some reason.  Anyway the mechanics are the same for reds (Hearts and Diamonds inclusive) so I updated the value for $p$.